# In Mercurial (tortoisehg), how do I view a file's history?

Tags: mercurial, repository, history

In tortoisehg, how do I view a file's history? Much like as the repo explorer, but instead of viewing the whole repo, I would like to view only a specific file's history.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view revision history for Mercurial file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459161/how-to-view-revision-history-for-mercurial-file)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use TortoiseHg, right click, view history. I think within the repo explorer/workbench you can go into file view mode and do the same from there

Comment: I tried this and I did not nitice it immediately. Right click the file -> view history. The main window listing the changeset will refresh/update and show only the changesets where the file was modofied. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer specific to TortoiseHg, but really either the other answer should be accepted or the question ought to be edited to ask how it's done with TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 39):

You can view the changes on a file by the following command:

```
hg log -f file_path
```

You can see more options by typing `hg log --help`