# `hg log --follow -r N` lists all revisions instead of listing rev N

Tags: mercurial

I need help in understanding **hg log --follow**.

```
$ hg log --help
...
 -f --follow              follow changeset history, or file history across
                          copies and renames
```

When I specify **-f**, the log output includes all the commits. I expected it to return commits related to the file changed in the given revision.
Is this the intended behaviour of the **-f** flag. If so, what is its use case?

```
/tmp:$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.5.3)
/tmp:$ mkdir hg-f
/tmp:$ cd hg-f
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg init
/tmp/hg-f:$ touch file0
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg add file0
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg commit -m 'file0 added'
/tmp/hg-f:$ touch foobar
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg add foobar
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg commit -m 'added foobar'
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg mv foobar barfoo
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg commit -m 'moved foobar'
/tmp/hg-f:$ hg log -v -r 2
changeset:   2:492bd607810c
tag:         tip
user:        'notalex'
date:        Tue Apr 16 09:10:25 2019 +0530
files:       barfoo foobar
description:
moved foobar

/tmp/hg-f:$ hg log -v -f -r 2
changeset:   2:492bd607810c
tag:         tip
user:        'notalex'
date:        Tue Apr 16 09:10:25 2019 +0530
files:       barfoo foobar
description:
moved foobar

changeset:   1:adfd98042078
user:        'notalex'
date:        Tue Apr 16 09:10:14 2019 +0530
files:       foobar
description:
added foobar

changeset:   0:64e5211bd019
user:        'notalex'
date:        Tue Apr 16 09:09:53 2019 +0530
files:       file0
description:
file0 added
```

Comment: In your pasted example, can you clarify what parts of it were unexpected?

Comment: @DaveInCaz - I suppose, Alex expected **do not see** r0, which is unrelated to r2 in terms of affected files at all

Comment: @LazyBadger, thank you it was below the scroll and I didn't see that!

Comment: @Alex is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459161/how-to-view-revision-history-for-mercurial-file

Comment: @DaveInCaz, my intention is to understand the **--follow** flag behaviour. Why does it exist if it is to return the entire log regardless?

Comment: I don't think anyone other than the people who created HG can answer a "why" question. Personally I use follow mainly for tracking renamed/moved files. You can also use it to track the history of a single file (as noted in the other question, linked above).

Comment: The linked question does not refer to **--follow** anywhere. I do not see that **-f** is used to follow the history of a single file, because in my above example; it is clearly not.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I misstated or badly garbled what I meant about the other question. I think what I meant was that follow is NOT needed for simple cases (no renames, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read [docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/log) more fully and carefully (I never used `-f` without filename, thus - read this related para first time too)

> File history is shown without following rename or copy history of
>   files. Use -f/--follow with a filename to follow history across
>   renames and copies. --follow without a filename will only show
>   **ancestors of the starting revision**.

0 **is** the ancestor of 2 in terms of DAG, OK. If you want to see and understand real purpose of `-f`, you have just compare output of (for your test-case)

`hg log barfoo` vs `hg log -f barfoo`